# I am selling my business, are there ways to (invest or spend) profit to save on tax cost?

Tags: income-tax, small-business, selling, new-york

I have multiple interests, through my broker, for the sale of my business. Are there laws that allow me to save on taxes by doing specific things with the sale money?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You need a lawyer and a tax accountant for a sale like this. They will be able to tell you if the proceeds are taxed as income (most likely) or capital gains and will help you structure the deal. How you spend the proceeds will not make a difference, although if it's a large amount and you plan to donate some to charity, you may be able to save on your total tax liability by creating a donor advised fund.

Keep in mind the broker is mostly interested in his commission and not about making the best deal for you. Get an attorney with experience in business sales.